# How to show error message if entered value matches any one of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on form input field and trying to show error message when user enters any of the following text

> JS01, PR03, HY79, FG36, VF42, HF23

Basically need to show error message only if user entered the above mentioned text.

```
<input type="text" name="prodcode" class="form-control"/>
```

Should we use regex to achieve this? or Any jquery/javascipt can do this?

Can anyone provide me an example?

Comment: Put the invalid values in an array, then use `indexOf()` within the `keypress` event of the `input` to check if the current value is within the array. If it is, then you can show you error message.

Comment: You can push the strings to an array and use jquerry inArray method to find if the value is present

Comment: Do you want it to check on post or whilst/after typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Jquery.inArray method to find out if the word user entered is in your defined array,

```
    var myarray = ["JS01", "PR03","HY79","FG36", "VF42","HF23"];
    var inputWord = $("input[name='prodcode']").val();

    if(jQuery.inArray(inputWord , myarray) !== -1){ //if the word exits
      //do what you want here
    }
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery indexof method.For ex:-

```
a = [JS01, PR03, HY79, FG36, VF42, HF23]


var value = $('input[name="prodcode"]').val();
var indexval = a.indexOf("value" ); // this will return -1 if not found else return index

if (indexval>=0){
// code for error

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this. The solution has been done on keydown

```
$(function(){
   var arr = ['JS01', 'PR03', 'HY79', 'FG36', 'VF42', 'HF23'];
    $('.form-control').keydown(function(){
   var inputval = $('.form-control').val();
   var k = $.inArray(inputval,arr);
   if(k != -1){
    alert('error');
   }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the includes method ( **[MDN includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** ) and check against an array which is prefilled with invalid strings.

```
var valuesToCheckFor = ["JS01", "PR03","HY79","FG36", "VF42","HF23"];

if( valuesToCheckFor.includes($('input[name="prodcode"]').val()) ) {
   // Do what you want.
}
```

**P.S.** you will have to add this code inside the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```js
var err = [ 'JS01', 'PR03', 'HY79', 'FG36', 'VF42', 'HF23' ];

$('#myInput').keyup(function (e){
  console.log("ERR", err.indexOf(this.value))
   if (err.indexOf(this.value) !== -1) {
      $('.error').css({display: 'block'})
   } else {
      $('.error').css({display: 'none'})
   }
})
```

```css
.error{
 color: red; 
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="prodcode" class="form-control"/>
<div class="error">Error</div>
```